# Pandas pivot_table to calculate share of margin

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a `Pandas` `DataFrame` named `df` that contains `n` `columns`. One of the `columns` is named `COUNT`, which shows how many times values in `A` occurs. `A` contains unique identifiers so every row has the value `1` in the `column` `COUNT`. It looks like this:

```
 A      B       C       D   E       COUNT
id1     cat1    1       a   15      1       
id2     cat2    2       b   14      1
id3     cat2    2       c   14      1
id4     cat1    1       d   15      1
id5     cat3    2       e   14      1
.....
```

Now I want to transform my `df` to look like this:

```
                14      15      
cat1_tot        NaN     2       
cat1_share      NaN     1       
cat2_tot        2       NaN     
cat2_share      0.6666  NaN     
cat3_tot        1       NaN     
cat3_share      0.3333  NaN
All             3       2
```

I can get `catx_tot` by using `pd.pivot_table`

```
pd.pivot_table(
     df, 
     values='COUNT', 
     index=['B'], 
     columns=['E'], 
     margins=True, 
     aggfunc=np.sum
)
```

But how do I add share to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

combine `groupby.size` with `groupby.transform`

```
size = df.groupby(['B', 'E']).size()
sums = size.groupby(level='E').transform(np.sum)
aggd = pd.concat([size, size / sums], axis=1, keys=['total', 'share'])

aggd.unstack().stack(0)
```

[image]

---

to get the `All` row

```
all_ = aggd.groupby(level='E').sum().total.rename(('All', 'total'))
aggd.unstack().stack(0).append(all_)
```

[image]